# How do I downgrade Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, camera, raspicam

I have Raspbian Jessie and recently I did `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and after that update, my Raspberry Pi camera stopped functioning. How do I downgrade Raspbian in order to get my camera working again? My camera is the Raspicam available from the Raspberry Pi Foundation.

EDIT:
The `dist-upgrade` was done from Jessie.

Comment: When you ran the dist-upgrade, was the pi running Wheezy or Jessie?

Comment: It was running Jessie, I'll update it.

Comment: If you can't figure out a way to downgrade, you could always backup your home directory, and then reinstall your OS, that way you would only lose some files, and not everything...

Comment: just reinstall the system, you can't downgrade easy way... apt-get has it's logs, so you can manually revert changes, but it's a hell of the work, did that once on Debian... really... better just format it and reinstall

Comment: I just decided to download the required files to my pc, and then just installed a backed up version of my OS from 1.5 months back.

Comment: Two years later, but: I'm chasing down an issue that may have appeared when I did a dist-upgrade while running Stretch in Feb 2018 and my RPi camera module lost one of its key features, but still produces images. Did you ever get to the bottom of this, or did you just reimage the flash drive and start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a very recent upgrade then try the interactive (default) mode of `aptitude` run with `sudo`; that has a TUI (text a.k.a. console user interface, done using `ncurses` if anyone is interested) package manager that can display all the versions currently available/installed of each package.

If you can identify which package is the problem and you can obtain an older version (as a `.deb`) file you can plonk it as root into `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and that application will allow you to change the version installed manually.

This is assuming other dependencies aren't an issue (the bottom area of the application turns from normal blue to red if the current combination of things is problematic) and other lines of listing.  The UI may take a bit of time to get used to but for starters I will tell you that `<cntl>-t` activates the menu bar and `q` for quit will escape out of things; the current "line" is highlighted in reverse and any line begging with `---` can be selected with `<enter>` to be expanded (when it changes to `--\`).

Hope this helps you to put your system back together..., here is a couple of screen-shots of aptitude in use showing a package that I HAVEN'T installed "solaar-gnome" (non of the four versions listed on the bottom of the second picture is installed - there is just a leading `p` indicating a package version is available) on the machine concerned (my Debian PC) as it would need a gnome package "gnome-shell" which I haven't got installed (the red line)!

[image: Picture of front page of aptitude in use]

[image: Picture of aptitude displaying details of a package]

Comment: This is great, however, it is not a package issue, the problem is that I need to rollback to an earlier version of Raspbian.

Comment: However you said you were already **on Jessie** - so `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` **will not have done  a *dist-upgrade* - it only will have done an *upgrade*** which means you may be able to down version an odd package *or few*!